# Carousel View Image source filter by List view Itemselected event xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, carousel, imagesource

i use xamarin.forms ,
i have List view with some category's when i click on any item in this list must navigate to another page has Carousel View in the top with image resource many photos for each category i pot image to explain everything  i use Itemselected event to pass the id value to from list to Carousel page to get only images belong for this category this is the code i use for that

```
private void categoryNamea_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        var categoryDetails = e.SelectedItem as category;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new categoryDetailspage(atractionDetails.id));

    }
```

and i bind the Carousel View

private categoryDetailsImageData _categoryDetailsImageData = new categoryDetailsImageData();
        public categoryDetailspage(int Id)
        {

```
        MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = _categoryDetailsImageData.GetcategorynDetailsImage(Id);
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

and in the model services

```
class categoryDetailsImageData
{
    private List<categoryDetailsImage11> _AtractionDetailsImage11 = new List<categoryDetailsImage11>
    {
        new categoryDetailsImage11{id=1},
        new categoryDetailsImage11{id=1},
        new categoryDetailsImage11{id=1},
        new categoryDetailsImage11{id=2},
        new categoryDetailsImage11{id=2},

    };

    public categoryDetailsImage11 GetcategoryDetailsImage11 (int userid)
    {
        return _categoryDetailsImage11.SingleOrDefault (e => e.id.Equals(userid));
    }
}
```

the model

```
class categoryDetailsImage11
{
    public int id { get; set; }


    public ImageSource image
    {
        get { return
                ImageSource.FromResource(string.Format("AnimalsِApp.Images.categoryDetailsImage.T" + id  +  ".jpg")); }

    }
}
```

my problem in 
MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = _categoryDetailsImageData.GetcategorynDetailsImage(Id);

i have this error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnimalsِApp.Models.categoryDetailsImage11' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) AnimalsِApp E:\AnimalsِApp1\AnimalsِApp\AnimalsِApp\Views\categoryDetailspage.xaml.cs   22  Active
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAIYS.jpg)

Comment: What's the code on line 22 of categoryDetailspage.xaml.cs? The exception would suggest that you are using a categoryDetailsImage11 object where a List or IEnumerable is expected.

Comment: You are returning single categoryDetailsImage11 and assign it to ItemsSource which should be IEnumerable (like list of categoryDetailsImage11 or soemthing like that)